# How to create incrementing columns?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have table with these column names.

```
Province/State
Country/Region
Lat
Long
1/22/20
1/23/20
1/24/20
1/25/20
...
...
3/21/20
```

I know to create first 4 columns but I don't know how create date column and increment it.

How can I implement such number of columns at once?
Thank you!

**Infected**

[image]

**Dead**

[image]

**Recovered**

[image]

**Object relational data model created by me**

[image]

**Question -:** Submit working Oracle script for your database schema.

Comment: You should rather have different rows for different days. Creating a column for each one is usually an antipattern.

Comment: Let's assume this is the first day which is 1/22/20. Then I have to enter values for that column and next day I have to `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN '1/23/20'` and add new values to that column. This must be the pattern, no? I get this idea from your comment

Comment: No you don't add another column to a table every day. That's madness. Why don't you explain **the business rule** you're trying to implement and we'll tell you how to model it.

Comment: No, exactly not. You have a **row** with the date (in one column) and the other data (in other columns) per day, **not** a column per day.

Comment: But my csv file consist of like that. It contains number of deaths in each day.

Comment: So you have a row with the day's date and the number of deaths on that day for each day.

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: I meant this is how you'd store the data in a relational table.

Comment: I am not who create that table with values. That table was given me by my lecturer.

Comment: Relational table store relations, they aren't spreadsheets. If you've been told otherwise, then they teach utter shenanigans. If not, they probably want you to do exactly this transformation.

Comment: I have add sample image

Comment: "That table was given me by my lecturer." - do you actually mean that the lecturer gave you a database table (or its definition); or gave you a spreadsheet and wants you to store that data in a database? If you include the actual assignment in the question things might be clearer. And maybe what you've been studying recently - e.g. pivot/unpivot operations, or external tables, or who knows...

Comment: @AlexPoole I have updated my question

Comment: Have you learned about [normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) ?

Comment: @Abra Yes I have learned

Comment: Can I use `pivot` keyword to do this also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to create a column-per-day; just create a table with columns for location, date and for each statistic (i.e. infected, recovered, dead, etc.) and then if you need to pivot them do that in a query (or in whatever middle-tier application [i.e. PHP, Java, .net] you're using to access the database).

Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Regions(
  id        VARCHAR2(6)
            CONSTRAINT regions__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id VARCHAR2(6)
            CONSTRAINT regions_parent__fk REFERENCES Regions ( id ),
  name      VARCHAR2(50)
            CONSTRAINT regions__name__nn NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT regions__name__u UNIQUE,
  latitude  NUMBER
            CONSTRAINT regions__lat__nn NOT NULL,
  longitude NUMBER
            CONSTRAINT regions__long__nn NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT regions__id__chk CHECK (
       ( parent_id IS     NULL AND REGEXP_LIKE( id, '^[A-Z]{2}$' ) )
    OR ( parent_id IS NOT NULL AND REGEXP_LIKE( id, '^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{1,3}$' ) )
  )
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN Regions.id        IS 'ISO 3166-2 Alpha-2 Country Code or ISO 3166-2 Province Code';
COMMENT ON COLUMN Regions.name      IS 'ISO 3166-2 English Short Name.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN Regions.latitude  IS 'Latitude of the region''s main city.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN Regions.longitude IS 'Longitude of the region''s main city.';

CREATE TABLE Virus_Statistics(
  id        NUMBER(20,0)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  location  VARCHAR2(6)
            CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__loc__nn NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__loc__fk REFERENCES Regions ( id ),
  datetime  DATE
            CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__dt__nn NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__dt__chk CHECK ( datetime = TRUNC( datetime ) ),
  infected  NUMBER(10,0),
  recovered NUMBER(10,0),
  dead      NUMBER(10,0),
  CONSTRAINT virus_statistics__loc__dt__u UNIQUE ( location, datetime )
);
```

Then you can input your data. For example, the regions would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO Regions ( id, parent_id, name, latitude, longitude )
SELECT 'TH',    NULL, 'Thailand',          15.00000,  101.00000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JP',    NULL, 'Japan',             36.00000,  138.00000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SG',    NULL, 'Singapore',          1.28333,  103.83333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NP',    NULL, 'Nepal',             28.16667,   84.25000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MY',    NULL, 'Malaysia',           2.50000,  112.50000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA',    NULL, 'Canada',            45.42472, - 75.69500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA-BC', 'CA', 'British Columbia',  48.40733, -123.32977 FROM DUAL;
```

And the first 3 columns of data would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO Virus_Statistics ( location, datetime, infected, recovered, dead )
SELECT 'TH',    DATE '2020-01-22', 2 AS i, 0 AS r, 0 AS d FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TH',    DATE '2020-01-23', 3, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TH',    DATE '2020-01-24', 5, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JP',    DATE '2020-01-22', 2, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JP',    DATE '2020-01-23', 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JP',    DATE '2020-01-24', 2, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SG',    DATE '2020-01-22', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SG',    DATE '2020-01-23', 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SG',    DATE '2020-01-24', 3, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NP',    DATE '2020-01-22', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NP',    DATE '2020-01-23', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NP',    DATE '2020-01-24', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MY',    DATE '2020-01-22', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MY',    DATE '2020-01-23', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'MY',    DATE '2020-01-24', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA-BC', DATE '2020-01-22', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA-BC', DATE '2020-01-23', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA-BC', DATE '2020-01-24', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Then if you want to output it as columns-per-day then use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         latitude,
         longitude,
         datetime,
         infected
  FROM   Virus_Statistics v
         INNER JOIN Regions r
         ON ( r.id = v.location )
)
PIVOT (
  MAX( infected )
  FOR datetime IN (
    DATE '2020-01-22' AS "2020-01-22",
    DATE '2020-01-23' AS "2020-01-23",
    DATE '2020-01-24' AS "2020-01-24"
  )
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME             | LATITUDE |  LONGITUDE | 2020-01-22 | 2020-01-23 | 2020-01-24
> :--------------- | -------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
> Japan            |       36 |        138 |          2 |          1 |          2
> Malaysia         |      2.5 |      112.5 |          0 |          0 |          0
> Singapore        |  1.28333 |  103.83333 |          0 |          1 |          3
> Nepal            | 28.16667 |      84.25 |          0 |          0 |          0
> British Columbia | 48.40733 | -123.32977 |          0 |          0 |          0
> Thailand         |       15 |        101 |          2 |          3 |          5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35bcf6cdbabf8b787a76d3b58000c19b)*

Comment: Now perhaps you can explain to the OP how he can populate these database tables from the data in the Excel spreadsheets that he posted images of in his question  :-)