# How to import many number of columns included csv file into SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, sql-loader

**This is my csv file**

[image]

I have tried to import this csv file by using `SQL Loader`.

**My `sql loader.txt`**

```
load data
 infile 'E:\time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv'
 into table confirmed
 fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
 (provice, country, lat, longi, date)
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\User>sqlldr dsda/dsda

control = E:\sql loader.txt

SQL*Loader-941: Error during describe of table CONFIRMED
ORA-04043: object CONFIRMED does not exist
```

There are lot of date columns in my csv file.

How can I import this csv using SQL Plus?

My csv file [Download link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xsEbLwTHpB05J8jVbdvrXZV72Gw87SWU)

For background about this [please see my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60819035/146325).

Comment: That's easy - user DSDA doesn't contain table named CONFIRMED. Create it first, then load data.

Comment: When creating this do I need to insert all that columns

Comment: Isn't there any method to load csv data into sql without defining columns

Comment: You have a bag full of apples. You want to "load" those apples into a basket. You don't have a basket. Buy a basket first. **In other words**: you have a CSV file full of data. You want to load data into a table. You don't have a table. Create table first.

Comment: Or, if you use some utility that creates a table for you - such as Oracle Application Express which is capable of creating a table based on input file - use it. Otherwise, you'll have to create it manually.

Comment: Not really, you need the target table to be defined, and to be able to map fields from your CSV to columns. You could split and pivot your worksheet to multiple simpler CSVs that align more closely with your existing tables, and use those with SQL\*Loader or as external tables. Or you could read and process the file line by line through PL/SQL but that seems like a lot of work. (I'm still curious about what your lecturer actually asked you to do - your solution seems to be getting rather complicated, and I can't help wondering if you've misinterpreted and overthought the actual requirement.)

Comment: @AlexPoole I was told to create new database and load csv data to the database.

Comment: you need to normalize that data first, but you can use sql developer, point to the csv file, we'll create the table AND load the data for you using a GUI

Comment: Second @thatjeffsmith comment re. normalizing data.  Your csv layout does NOT reflect properly normalized data.  If our comments about normalizing data / data normalization mean nothing to you, then your education has missed a critical subject .. like going to calculus without having studied algebra.  Data normalization concepts are the very foundation of relational database design.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - the Seeker has already had [a schooling in normalization from us](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60819035/146325) :-) They need to get the data out of the spreadsheet before they can populate normalized tables.

Comment: Now I am trying to import my csv into python and covert date columns into single columns with infected values and export it as another csv file.